# Spending Time Rendering Transparent Tiles

Tags: rendering, transparency

I'm doing a motion tracking scene, and I'm wondering why blender is spending so much time rendering the transparent tiles.  If somebody could explain how to prevent this, that would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: This post may be relevant. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32127/is-there-a-way-to-have-cycles-skip-rendering-alpha/32131#32131

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27531/599

Comment: wouldn't it be neat if you could easily 2d track the region render border and keyframe it?

Comment: @zeffii That would be awesome! And it could be used for objects within blender too..

Comment: The reason for this slowness is cycles still sends rays to sample the background, even though it's just a sky texture/transparency. There isn't much of a way to avoid it atm.. Perhaps this will be optimized further in the future.

Comment: @gandalf3 http://i.stack.imgur.com/UQpGT.gif